# Rechart value labels above x-axis labels

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, recharts

Is it possible to show the value labels of the y-value below the x-axis instead of showing them inside the chart in Rechart? I have found nothing similar to this in the examples on the Recharts page and the API does not have options for this either. (At least I didn't find them) An example of what I mean is in the link below.

[value labels below x-axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/om8B9.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use the "position" prop with only "y" value to set the position along Y-Axis. This will only fix the Y-Axis position and the X-Axis would change, hence giving you the Tooltip the way you require.

Comment: Did you link the correct code example? However I do not need the tooltip there, I need them to be static to print the chart in a report. thx in advance.